# Using Select with SingleOrDefault in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

Is there any way to specify which columns to retrieve when using `SingleOrDefault` with Entity Framework?

Something like this:

```
_messageRepository.FirstOrDefaultAsync(input.Id).select(m => m.title, m.Id)
```

It would be a very heavy query if I want to return all data ..

Thanks

Comment: what is the `input.Id` parameter for?

Comment: ti filter the result.

Comment: this won't compile, unless input.Id is of Expression<Func<T,bool>> type. Why don't you try to let EF select the appropriate columns and then execute the query? like _messageRepository.Select(x=>new{x.title,x.Id}).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x=>x.Id==input.Id) (is what I guess you're trying)

Comment: have a read of this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738633(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your pseudo code is not entirely clear, but you probably simply want something like:

```
var result = await _messageRepository.Where(m => m.Id == input.Id)
                                     .Select(m => new { m.Title, m.Id })
                                     .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```